# How to sign a file with a specific public key and check what key was used for signing in GPG?

Tags: gnupg, sign, verify

I have generated 3 pairs of public and private keys using `gpg`. I would like to sign a file with one of this 3 public keys and then verify which of this 3 keys was used to sign the file.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried to sign the file with `gpg --sign --default-key person1@gmail.com data.txt` but do not know if its the right direction. Besides, what about veryfing?

Comment: You don't sign with a public key.

Answer (score 4):

```
gpg -d data.txt.gpg
```

Will decrypt the file (default -o is data.txt) and tell you which key signed it. If for some reason having a decrypted copy of the file on disk is a problem you might try

```
gpg -d -o /dev/null data.txt.gpg
```

It'll still tell you whether the signature was valid and what key signed it.

To specify which key to *use* when signing:

```
gpg --sign -u <key-id> somefile.txt
```

Comment: But what if I have more than 1 key file and want to check if one of them was used for signing?

Comment: When you decrypt, and the signature is good, it will have a line to the effect of "Signature made MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Time Zone\n using RSA key <key fingerprint> \n Good signature from "Your Name (with comment) <address@site.com>" [trust level]". That fingerprint corresponds to the key used. Try it out on a test file and you'll see.

Comment: The OP wants to sign with the _public_ _key_. `gpg --sign` does not sign with the public key. You encrypt with the public key and sign with the private key. Always.